# How to delay between 2 animations?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am dismissing one modal view controller and then immediately presenting another modal view controller however I cannot currently use animation on both of them only the second one.

Is there anyway to delay the process so that the user experiences both animations?

The code below currently works however user only sees the second animation obviously:

```
// First one configure
detailViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
detailViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl; 
[self presentModalViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];

//Dismiss first one
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO]; 

//Immediately configure and show second one
navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
navController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
```

Comment: can I assume you've already tried `
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];` without success??

Comment: [UIView transitionWithView:mysuperview duration:0.75 options:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight animations:^{ [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO]; } completion:nil]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is now a completetion block available in present modal view controller. See this [LINK](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/presentViewController%3aanimated%3acompletion%3a). This is available in iOS5.0 +.

This has the advantage that you don't need to estimate the timer delay if you were to use a timer solution.

Just put the code for your second animation in the block:

```
//Block safe reference to self to prevent retain cycles
__block typeof (self) selfReference = self;

// First one configure
detailViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
detailViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl; 
[self presentModalViewController:detailViewController animated:YES completion:
^{
    //Dismiss first one
    [selfReference dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO]; 

    //Immediately configure and show second one
    navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    navController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [selfReference presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
 }];
```

Comment: This is the correct solution. Attempting to use a timer to guess at when your first view controller has finished animating is a hack.

Comment: This is excellent!  The two animations look awesome together thanks mate, plus first time using blocks - so handy!

Comment: No problem. I'd forgotten to worry about retain cycles in blocks though, have a look at the edit, I've replaced self with a selfReference suitable for blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Make a selector that does the following:

```
- (void)showSecondModalVC {
  //Dismiss first one
  [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO]; 

  //Immediately configure and show second one
  navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
  navController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
  [self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
}
```

An then in the main piece of code:

```
// First one configure
detailViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
detailViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl; 
[self presentModalViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];

[self performSelector:@selector(showSecondModalVC) 
         withObject:nil 
         afterDelay:0.5f];
```

You will have to look closely and see how much it takes for the first modal to show so the animations look good.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in some other style.

```
detailViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
detailViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl; 
[self presentModalViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO]; 

[self performSelector:@selector(someFunction) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];

- (void) someFunction{
//Immediately configure and show second one
navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
navController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
// First one configure
detailViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
detailViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl; 
[self presentModalViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];

//Dismiss first one
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO]; 
NSTimer Timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(openSecondView) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];


-(void)openSecondView
{
    //Immediately configure and show second one
    navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    navController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
}
```

Happy Coding...